# Why was this question closed as "not a real question"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This is regarding this question
[How do I convert a doubly recursive method to a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334744/how-do-i-convert-a-recursive-method-to-a-loop#comment19924492_14334744)

The question is about converting a recursive function with 2 recursive calls to a loop. This is pretty hard to do. I tried it, and got completely confused :P

So I came back to see if anyone had an answer. But the question was closed by then with the reason being "not a real question".

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is
>   ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot
>   be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this
>   question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

I don't think this question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical. And I am sure someone smart enough to figure it out will be able to answer it. I even found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531668/which-recursive-functions-cannot-be-rewritten-using-loops) answer which says

> there is nothing that can be done with recursion and that cannot be
>   done with a loop and a stack.

So yes, the question can definitely be answered. So can anyone explain why it was closed? And is there a way to ask for it to be reopened?

Comment: I'd vote to reopen if I had the rep for it.

Comment: Same here. But I don't have the rep either.

Comment: Voted to reopen.. I would like to get an answer to that question too..

Comment: Probably wouldn't have been closed if the OP had shown their attempt at solving it. "I tried but it didn't work" without the corresponding code is not enough.